# Load from file function incompletely loads values to program

Tags: c, file, struct

I am writing a, sort of, music playlist database. A user can input up to ten playlists and songs can be saved in this struct array, along with their respective information which are title, artist, and album.

I'm encountering a problem with my load function. Whenever I try to load existing data from a file, it correctly saves the data from the first playlist and its songs. But when it comes to the second playlist, the song information are not saved. Below is a screenshot of a sample run:

[image: Sample_Run]

This is supposed to be loaded from this txt file:

[image: Txt_file]

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

///STRUCTURE DECLARATIONS

typedef struct{
    char title[50], artist[50], album[50];
}songdetails;

typedef struct {
    songdetails tracks[50];
} tunes;

typedef struct playlist{
    char name[50];
    int songCount;
    
    tunes songs;
    
}collection;  

//FUNCTIONS
void addPlaylist(struct playlist *playlist, int (*index)){
    char temp[50];
    printf("What do you want your playlist to be called?: ");
    scanf(" %49[^\n]", temp);
    bool found = false;
    for(int i=0; i<(*index);i++){
        if((strcmp(temp, playlist[(i)].name))==0){
            found = true;
            //*index = i;
            printf("%s already exists!\n", playlist[(i)].name);
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!found){
        strcpy(playlist[(*index)].name, temp);
        printf("Playlisst successfully added!\n");
        (*index)++;
    }
}

void addSong(struct playlist *playlist, int index){
    int choice;
    if (index==0){
        printf("There are no playlists yet!\n\n");
    }else {
        printf("\nTHE PLAYLISTS AVAILABLE ARE:\n");
        for (int i=0; i<index; i++){
            printf("[%d] %s\n", i+1, playlist[i].name);
        }
        printf("Enter choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        playlist[choice-1].songCount++;

        
        printf("Enter song title: ");
        scanf(" %49[^\n]", playlist[choice-1].songs.tracks[playlist[choice-1].songCount].title);
        printf("Enter song artist: ");
        scanf(" %49[^\n]", playlist[choice-1].songs.tracks[playlist[choice-1].songCount].artist);
        printf("Enter song album: ");
        scanf(" %49[^\n]", playlist[choice-1].songs.tracks[playlist[choice-1].songCount].album);
        
        printf("Song successfully added!\n");
    }
}

void printPlaylist(struct playlist *playlist, int index){
    int choice;
    if(index==0){
        printf("There are no saved playlists.\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("THE PLAYLISTS AVAILABLE ARE: \n");
        for (int i=0; i<index; i++){
                printf("[%d] %s\n", i+1, playlist[i].name);
            }
        printf("\nEnter choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        printf("PLAYLIST: %s\n", playlist[choice-1].name);
        printf("SONG COUNT: %d\n", playlist[choice-1].songCount);
        for(int j=0; j<playlist[choice-1].songCount; j++){
            printf("    SONG TITLE: %s\n", playlist[choice-1].songs.tracks[j+1].title);
            printf("    SONG ARTIST: %s\n", playlist[choice-1].songs.tracks[j+1].artist);
            printf("    SONG ALBUM: %s\n\n", playlist[choice-1].songs.tracks[j+1].album);    
        }
    }
}

void printAll(struct playlist *playlist, int index){
    if(index==0){
        printf("There are no saved playlists!\n");
    }else {
        for(int i=0; i<index;i++){
            printf("PLAYLIST: %s\n", playlist[i].name);
            printf("SONG COUNT: %d\n", playlist[i].songCount);
            for(int j=0; j<playlist[i].songCount; j++){
                printf("    SONG TITLE: %s\n", playlist[i].songs.tracks[j+1].title);
                printf("    SONG ARTIST: %s\n", playlist[i].songs.tracks[j+1].artist);
                printf("    SONG ALBUM: %s\n\n", playlist[i].songs.tracks[j+1].album);    
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
///////////////////////this is the function in question:////////////////////////
void loadPlaylistData(struct playlist *playlist, int *count){
    int i=0, j=0;
    FILE *fp = fopen("playlistData.txt", "r");
    
    if((fp = fopen("playlistData.txt", "r"))==NULL){
        printf("There are no files to be loaded.\n");
    } else{
        fscanf(fp, "%d", count);
        if((*count)!=0){
            for(i;i<(*count);i++){ 
                fscanf(fp,  " %49[^\n]", playlist[i].name);
                fscanf(fp, "%d\n", &playlist[i].songCount);
                for(j; j<playlist[i].songCount;j++){
                    fscanf(fp, " %49[^\n]", playlist[i].songs.tracks[j+1].title);
                    fscanf(fp, " %49[^\n]", playlist[i].songs.tracks[j+1].artist);
                    fscanf(fp, " %49[^\n]", playlist[i].songs.tracks[j+1].album);
                }
        }
        printf("Successfully loaded data!\n");
        }else{
            printf("There are no playlists to be loaded.\n");
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
}

void savePlaylistData(struct playlist *playlist, int *count){
    if ((*count)!=0){
        FILE *fp = fopen("playlistData.txt", "w");
        fprintf(fp, "%d\n", (*count));
        for(int i=0;i<(*count);i++){ 
            fprintf(fp,  "%s\n", playlist[i].name);
            fprintf(fp, "%d\n", playlist[i].songCount);
            for(int j=0; j<playlist[i].songCount;j++){
                fprintf(fp, "%s\n", playlist[i].songs.tracks[j+1].title);
                fprintf(fp, "%s\n", playlist[i].songs.tracks[j+1].artist);
                fprintf(fp, "%s\n", playlist[i].songs.tracks[j+1].album);
            }
        }
    }else printf("There is no data to be saved!\n");
}

//MAIN FUNCTION
int main(){
    struct playlist playlistx[10];
    int choice;
    int index = 0;

    loadPlaylistData(playlistx, &index);

    while(1){
        printf("\n@@@@@@@@@@@@ MENU @@@@@@@@@@@@\n");
        printf("[1] Add a playlist\n");
        printf("[2] Add song to playlist\n"); 
        printf("[3] Remove song from playlist\n");
        printf("[4] View a playlist\n");
        printf("[5] View all data\n");
        printf("[6] Exit\n");

        printf("Enter choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        if (choice==1){
            addPlaylist(playlistx, &index);
        }else if (choice==2){
            addSong(playlistx, index);
        // }else if (choice==3){
        //     removeSong(playlistx);
        //     printf("\nSong successfully removed!\n");
        }else if (choice==4){
            printPlaylist(playlistx, index);
        }else if (choice==5){
            printAll(playlistx, index);
        }else if (choice==6){
            printf("Goodbye!\n");
            savePlaylistData(playlistx, &index);
            break;
        }else {
            printf("Invalid choice!\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In `loadPlaylistData()` at `for(j; j<playlist[i].songCount;j++){` You need to reset `j = 0` here: `for(j = 0; j<playlist[i].songCount;j++){`.

Comment: Note: If you had compiled with warnings (e.g.) `-Wall`, the compiler would have flagged the errors in your `for` loops as `statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]`